# Firebase UI Auth (ProfileScreen) detect when a user updates their Display Name

Tags: flutter, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-authentication

I'm using the [firebase_ui_auth package](https://pub.dev/packages/firebase_ui_auth) to control auth and my ProfileScreen.
I'm building a Flutter app using Firestore/Firebase Auth. When the user account is created I have a Cloud Function trigger to create a user document `users/${uid}`.

What I want to happen is when a user updates their Display Name that the update syncs with Firestore. I have a Provider (Riverpod) that listens to `AuthStateChanges`, however, updating a user doesn't trigger that.

There are no Cloud Functions for this kind of trigger.

How can I listen for these kinds of changes (and get the actual change)? I can easily update Firestore once I understand where to listen for changes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [**userChanges method**](https://pub.dev/documentation/firebase_auth/latest/firebase_auth/FirebaseAuth/userChanges.html) which will listen for any changes in user profile, So you can update the displayName accordingly as follows :

```
import 'package:firebase_auth/firebase_auth.dart';
import 'package:cloud_firestore/cloud_firestore.dart';

void listenForUserProfileChanges() {
  FirebaseAuth.instance.userChanges().listen((User? user) async {
    if (user != null) {
      String newDisplayName = user.displayName ?? '';
      String uid = user.uid;

      try {
        // Update the displayName in the Firestore document
        await FirebaseFirestore.instance
            .collection('users')
            .doc(uid)
            .update({'displayName': newDisplayName});
        print('DisplayName updated successfully in Firestore document.');
      } catch (error) {
        print('Error updating DisplayName in Firestore: $error');
      }

      print('User $uid updated their displayName to $newDisplayName');
    } else {
      print('User is null');
    }
  });
}

void main() {
  listenForUserProfileChanges();
}
```

I have wrapped this into a function but you can specify anywhere in your application.

Reference : [**userChanges method**](https://pub.dev/documentation/firebase_auth/latest/firebase_auth/FirebaseAuth/userChanges.html)

Answer (score 0):

Firebase UI author here.

You can now use `DisplayNameChangedAction`:

```dart
ProfileScreen(
  actions: [
    DisplayNameChangedAction((context, oldName, newName) {
      // do something with the new name
    }),
  ],
)
```